# How to open same mobile application with different types of users and switching between them using appium

Tags: java, automation, appium

I have little confusion related to automating ola kind of mobile apps. In my current project, I have similar kind of mobile app where driver and passenger UI interact with each other based on their respective actions.

How to automate such scenario using appium means in a given test script how I will be validating both the UI and more importantly opening same application twice but different for users(driver and passenger) and switching between the two app to validate the functionality on both the UI. Please help me here as I am stuck here.

Comment: Can you achieve intended result manually? Is it possible to open your app multiple times on the same device, or are you going to use multiple devices?

Comment: Currently for manual, I use two devices. So for automation, could you please suggest how can I achieve it using appium. Means my script will run  and do validation for both driver and passenger

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this in Appium you will need to run 2 Appium Nodes that will handle your devices separately.

Example code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilitiesOne = new DesiredCapabilities(); //set for 1st device
DesiredCapabilities capabilitiesTwo = new DesiredCapabilities(); //set for 2nd device
...

String hubOneURL = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"; // Appium node for 1st device
String hubTwoURL = "http://127.0.0.1:4733/wd/hub"; // Appium node for 2nd device

AndroidDriver driverOne = new AndroidDriver(new URL(hubOneURL), capabilitiesOne);
AndroidDriver driverTwo = new AndroidDriver(new URL(hubTwoURL), capabilitiesTwo);

driverOne.doStuff();
driverTwo.doMoreStuff();
```

And you start your Appium nodes like this:

```
appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 //1st node
appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4733 //2nd node
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.Will definitely try this approach and update you 

Answer (score 0):

You must run two instance of Appium server with different port and bootstrap port.

Start your Appium server for **passenger app** from terminal or Appium desktop app in port 4732 and bootstrap port 4733

```
>appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4732 -bp 4733 --session-override
```

Start your Appium server for **driver app** from terminal or Appium desktop app in port 4734 and bootstrap port 4735

```
>appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4734 -bp 4735 --session-override
```

> you must also use the device **udid** in your desiredCapabilities to specify the driver for the device. **udid** is unique device identifier. you can find device udid using **adb devices** command.

Define your **DesiredCapabilities** for both passenger and driver app specifying **deviceName**, **udid**, **platformName**, **automationName**, (**appPackage**, **appActivity**) or (**app**)

> you may need to include **newCommandTimeout** in your DesiredCapabilities.

Define and initialize **AppiumDriver** for both passenger and driver app like following.

```
public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> pDriver; //passenger app
public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> dDriver; //driver app
pDriver= new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4732/wd/hub"), pCaps);
//pCaps = passenger app DesiredCapabilities
dDriver=new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4734/wd/hub"), dCaps);
//dCaps = driver app DesiredCapabilities
```

> You must define AppiumDriver as **static**
>
> bootstrap port > port to use on device to talk to Appium(Android only)
>
> Session-0verride > Enables session override
>
> newCommandTimeout > How long (in seconds) Appium will wait for a new command from the client before assuming the client quit and ending the session

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I did not get what is bootstrap port here , also what --session override does here. And why I may need newCommandTimeOut in DesiredCapabilities

Comment: **bootstrap port** > port to use on device to talk to Appium(Android only). 

**session-0verride** > Enables session override. 

**newCommandTimeout** > How long (in seconds) Appium will wait for a new command from the client before assuming the client quit and ending the session.